# Generating Sudoku in Java

Tags: java, sudoku

I have some problems with java programming. This is first time i encounter java so please be patient becouse i may miss absolutely basics. Anyway long story short i have sudoku to do and i encountered fiew problems.I need to take random numbers to make sudoku board or rather it's values.

If you dont know what is sudoku about, there have to be only digits from 1-9 and they can't repeat in row column and 3x3 square. Board itself is 9x9 so it can be divided into 9 3x3 squares.

And the main issue is that randomly generated values sometimes make patterns imposibble to solve. Therefore i tried to repeat random draw of those impossible to solve lines to avoid those situations but as i expierienced i can't do that. Here is the code and Thanks for help  ;)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class tabela {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      boolean bylo[] = new boolean[10];//this array tells me if the number is avalible to pick

      boolean wysw[][] = new boolean[9][9];//not used yet it is ment to be used while displaying array in GUI
      int tabela[][] = new int[9][9];//here will be generated values of sudoku

      for(int i=0; i<9;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
               tabela[i][j]=0; //filling array with 0s

      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {


             // System.out.print("a"); <- debugging tools
          out:for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                  //System.out.print("b");
                  for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
                      bylo[h] = false;
                  //System.out.print("c");
                  {
                      int zaokr1 = i + 1, zaokr2 = j + 1; //setting values other than j and i +1 
                      int resz;                           //bcouse i want to set values divided by 3 
                      if (zaokr1 % 3 != 0) { //
                          resz = i % 3;
                          zaokr1 = zaokr1 + (3 - resz);//rounding up to 3 to determine in which 3x3 square we are
                      }
                      if (zaokr2 % 3 != 0) {            // 1 2 3
                          resz = j % 3;                 // 4 5 6
                          zaokr2 = zaokr2 + (3 - resz); // 7 8 9
                      }

                      int c = i, d = j;               //Here i take agan values from i and j 
                      while (c > 0) {                 //
                          c--;                        //and i set values of numbers in column true to 
                          bylo[tabela[c][d]] = true;  //reroll them later
                      }
                      c = i;d = j;                    //same here
                      while (d > 0) {                 //
                          d--;                        //this time for rows
                          bylo[tabela[c][d]] = true;  //
                      }

                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 1 && zaokr2 / 3 == 1) //those are 3x3 squares from 1 - 9(
                                                              //this is first one
                      {

                          bylo[tabela[0][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][2]] = true;


                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 1 && zaokr2 / 3 == 2)//second
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[0][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][5]] = true;

                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 1 && zaokr2 / 3 == 3)//third
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[0][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[0][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[1][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[2][8]] = true;

                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 2 && zaokr2 / 3 == 1)//fourth
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[3][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][2]] = true;

                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 2 && zaokr2 / 3 == 2)//fifth
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[3][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][5]] = true;
                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 2 && zaokr2 / 3 == 3)//sixth
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[3][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[3][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[4][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[5][8]] = true;
                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 3 && zaokr2 / 3 == 1)//seventh
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[6][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][2]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][0]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][1]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][2]] = true;
                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 3 && zaokr2 / 3 == 2)//eighth
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[6][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][5]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][3]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][4]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][5]] = true;
                      }
                      if (zaokr1 / 3 == 3 && zaokr2 / 3 == 3)//ninth
                      {
                          bylo[tabela[6][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[6][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[7][8]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][6]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][7]] = true;
                          bylo[tabela[8][8]] = true;
                      }
                  }
                  //System.out.print("d");
                  int licznik=0;
                  for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                       if(bylo[x]==true){licznik++;} //here i count if all values are not blocked already
                  }
                  if(licznik==10)
                  {
                      if(i<=3){i=0;j=0;}
                      if(i>3&&i<=6) {i=3;j=0;}
                      if(i>6) {i=6;j=0;}
                      break out;//i read somwhere that this goes back to the certain point ;)
                  }

                  tabela[i][j] = RandomBeetween(1, 10);
                  if (bylo[tabela[i][j]] == true) {
                      do {

                          tabela[i][j] = RandomBeetween(1, 10);//randomizing numbers

                      } while (bylo[tabela[i][j]] == true);
                      bylo[tabela[i][j]] = true;//and setting their value in bool array to true
                      System.out.print(tabela[i][j]);
                  } else {
                      if (bylo[tabela[i][j]] == false) {
                          bylo[tabela[i][j]] = true;
                          System.out.print(tabela[i][j]);
                      }
                      //for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
                      //  System.out.print(bylo[x]+"   ");
                  }



                  //System.out.println("e  ");
              }
              for(int a=0;a<9;a++)
                  System.out.print(tabela[i][a]+"  ");System.out.print("f");


          }



      }
      static int RandomBeetween ( int min, int max)//just random  in custom range
      {
          Random random = new Random();
          int a1 = random.nextInt(max - min);
          int a2 = a1 + min;
          return a2;

      }


}
```

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for the words ___java sudoku code___ ?

Comment: Yes i did but i saw just sudoku solvers ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to try to figure out all your code. I'm going to suggest a basic process for making this problem work.

First, you're working in an object-oriented programming language. I'd start with making a class SudokuPuzzle. I would give it these methods (to start):

```
class SudokuPuzzle {
    // A constructor that initializes to all zeros.
    public SudokuPuzzle() { ... }

    // Create a legal finished board
    public randomizeBoard() { ... }

    // Take the legal board and hide some squares to make it a puzzle
    public turnIntoAPuzzle() { ... }

    // Output
    public display() { ... }
}
```

Doing this will give you a nice, clean object to work with, and it will break your problem down into pieces that are more easily managed. I think you'll find even randomizeBoard() is difficult. After all, consider the rules of Sudoku:

- Each row must contain each number exactly once
- Each column must contain each number exactly once
- Each square of 9 mini-squares must contain each number exactly once

So randomizeBoard() is not a trivial task. I've been programming computers for 45 years, and I don't have a clear view of how I'd write it.

But THEN you can move into turnIntoAPuzzle(). This is actually probably an easier problem. You can randomly pick a cell and decide whether you can safely hide that cell based on the rules you program. For instance, in the easy mode, if this cell is hidden:

- Can it be determined based on all the other cells in this box of 9?
- Can it be determined based on this row?
- Can it be determined based on this column?

If so, the cell is safe to hide. You can use a random function to find cells that aren't hidden yet and go through your rules.

For medium hardness, add rules like:

- Can I determine this cell based on a combination of this square of 9, this row, and this column?

If at some point, all your tests return "no, I can't", then you would remove that cell from future hiding-consideration and randomly pick from the remaining not-yet-hidden cells.

Loop until the list of "might be able to hide" cells is zero.

--

This post provides a pattern of how to approach problems like this. Break it down. Figure out how you would do it manually, without a computer, then turn that into instructions for the computer.

I think randomizing the board is actually harder than hiding some cells, because that's a pretty straightforward algorithm. I'm not sure randomizing the board is simple, but maybe it's actually not bad. But I think it's possible to go down bad paths.